# Listar links de uma página

Tags: javascript

Bom dia!
tenho este script que lista todos os links de uma página, porém não trás o nome do link mas apenas o endereço, tem como trazer o nome do link ao invés do endereço?

```
javascript: var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');var b = a.length; if(b != 0){ document.write('<h1> Lista de Links </h1> '); for (i = 0; i < b; i++){ document.write('<pre><a href=\'' + a[i] + '\'>' + a[i] + '</a>' + '</pre> ');}} else{ document.write('Nenhum link encontrado');}
```

Comment: testando as respostas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É que você mesmo está especificando no código para trazer a URL como o nome do link.
Para pegar a URL do item listado:

```
a[i].href
```

Para pegar o nome do link:

```
a[i].innerHTML
```

Então seguindo o seu código ficará assim:

```
javascript: var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');var b = a.length; if(b != 0){ document.write('<h1> Lista de Links </h1> '); for (i = 0; i < b; i++){ document.write('<pre><a href=\'' + a[i].href + '\'>' + a[i].innerHTML + '</a>' + '</pre> ');}} else{ document.write('Nenhum link encontrado');}
```

Vale lembrar que o protocolo JAVASCRIPT: não é mais usado por padrão, agora se você estiver querendo usar como link está parcialmente correto.

Se for pra criar um utilitário pra navegadores aconselho criar aplicativos de navegador, Chrome, Opera e Firefox.
Não usei o Edge ainda pra saber se têm.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade ele trás todos os elementos. Só que você está imprimindo o elemento `a` dentro do atributo de outro elemento `a`.

Faça dessa forma:

```
const a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (let b of a) {
    document.write('<pre><a href=\'' + b.getAttribute("href") + '\'>' + b.innerText + '</a>' + '</pre> ');
}
```

Comment: Este travou o navegador, mas obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trocar por este:

```
// Capturamos todos os links:
const links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

// Criamos a div que irá conter todos os links.
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<h1>Lista de Links</h1><br><br><br>';
div.style.padding = '20px';

// Iteramos sobre todos os links.
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  const self = links[i];

  // Caso não haja texto:
  if (self.innerText === '') continue;

  // Criar o elemento da iteração atual
  // e incluí-lo na div que criamos acima.
  const code = document.createElement('code');
  code.innerHTML = `<a href="${self.href}">${self.innerText}</a><br><br>`;

  div.appendChild(code);
}

// Substituir todo o conteúdo do body
// pela lista de links.
document.body.innerHTML = div.outerHTML;
```

Tentei explicar com comentários através do código.

Boa tarde!

Comment: Este travou o navegador, mas obrigado

Comment: Você colocou ele no console ou na URL? Nesse script, você deve colocá-lo no console. Para isso, aperte **F12** e depois vá à aba console. Cole o código lá e dê enter.

Comment: Ah sim agora entendi, obrigado